# No compile_commands.json file using cmake with vs code on windows

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake, clang-tidy

I am trying to integrate the Clang-Tidy static analysis tool into my build system.
I am getting a few issues with my setup.

Step `cmake -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON ..` is not generating compile_commands.json file.
Hence, clang-tidy is giving below error.

`>cmake --build .` result

```
Could not auto-detect compilation database from directory "C:/dev/my-project/build/compile_commands.json"
  No compilation database found in C:\dev\my-project\build\compile_commands.json or any parent directory
  fixed-compilation-database: Error while opening fixed database: no such file or directory
  json-compilation-database: Error while opening JSON database: no such file or directory
  Running without flags.
  Error while processing C:\dev\my-project\src\.
CUSTOMBUILD : error : unable to handle compilation, expected exactly one compiler job in '' [clang-diagnostic-error] [C:\dev\my-project\build\analyze_clang_tidy.vcxproj]
  Suppressed 1 warnings (1 in non-user code).
  Use -header-filter=.* to display errors from all non-system headers. Use -system-headers to display errors from system headers as well.
```

`Clang-tidy.cmake` file

```
set(CLANG_TIDY_CHECKS "-checks='${CLANG_TIDY_CHECKS}'")

            add_custom_target(analyze_clang_tidy ALL
                COMMAND ${CLANG_TIDY}
                -p ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/compile_commands.json
                ${CLANG_TIDY_CHECKS}
                -header-filter='.*'
                ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/
                WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
                COMMENT "Static code analysis with Clang-Tidy"
            )
```

Please also find the configuration result

```
-- Building for: Visual Studio 14 2015
-- Selecting Windows SDK version  to target Windows 10.0.17763.
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.0.24215.1
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
Default build type: Debug
iD MSVC
-- ccache found and enabled
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/dev/my-project/build
```

I have a simple hello world `int main() {...}` in my `../src/` folder.

Please suggest to me how to generate the compile_commands.json file using CMake with VS code on windows.
Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS.html

Specifically this Note:

> **Note** This option is implemented only by Makefile Generators and the Ninja. It is ignored on other generators.

Instead, you could write a python script which would generate that format for you, similar to this tool: https://github.com/nickdiego/compiledb

Or, actually, you don't need `compile_commands.json`. You can define `CMAKE_<LANG>_CLANG_TIDY` variable to trigger clang-tidy automatically:  https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_CLANG_TIDY.html

See how I did this for my project [1](https://github.com/VeriBlock/alt-integration-cpp/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L157) [2](https://github.com/VeriBlock/alt-integration-cpp/blob/master/cmake/clang-tidy.cmake) [3](https://github.com/VeriBlock/alt-integration-cpp/blob/master/.clang-tidy)

Comment: Thanks, @warchantua! I am taking your project as a reference for setting up my project build system.